# Correctly updating stand-alone QGIS install on Windows?

Tags: qgis, windows, update

I want to update QGIS 2.14.6 to 2.14.12 in Windows.

Aims:

- Receive all projects
- Receive all additional third party plugins

My plan at the moment is:

1. Copy folder "plugins" within .qgis/python
2. Delete folder .qgis
3. Delete QGIS 2.14.6 and their desktop assignments
4. Install 2.14.12
5. Paste folder "plugins"

Question:

1. Is anything wrong in 1-5, if yes: What?
2. Any other points that need to be considered?

Comment: Are you using the standalone installer or the OSGeo4W installer?

Comment: Standalone installer from this site:
https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Folder `.qgis` is not used since QGIS 2.0, `.qgis2`is used instead.

You can do step 1, step 2 is not necessary, and the next ones are done by the installer of QGIS 2.14.12.

The last step is not necessary, because nothing in that folder gets touched by the installer.

Your steps might be relevant for the next big release, QGIS 3.0.

Comment: OK. A follow up question:

Future (End of 2017):
Would it more easy to upgrade from 2.18 to 3 or would it the same work to update from 2.14 to 3?
Are there recommendations?

Comment: I would keep the QGIS 2.14 LTR version as a fallback for some time. Both can coexist on Windows. You can migrate your projects if you feel comfortable with the new version. So switching to 2.18 **now** is not a good choice if you are working with the LTR.